# Custom query using WP_Query is not working

Tags: wp-query, customization

I have a little problem with a custom query that only should get used when the user is on the home page (`is_home()`) and when `is_main_query == true` . I have a function hooked to `pre_get_posts` in order to use my custom query, but unfortunately when the function is called, the html-<`body`> is empty. Have I missed something?

**functions.php**

```
<?php
    function my_function(){

      if( is_home() && $query->is_main_query()){
      global $wp_query;

      // the arguments

      $args = array(
          'post_type'         => 'post',
          'posts_per_page'    => '3',
      );

      // the query

      $query = new WP_Query($args);

      // the Loop

      if( $query->have_posts()) { ?>
          <section class="recent-posts clear">
          <?php while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post() ; ?>                
              <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class( 'left'   ); ?>>
                  <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php post_thumbnail( 'thumbnail' );?></a>              
                  <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>                
              </article>
          <?php endwhile; ?>                
          </section>
          <?php 
      }

      // restore original Post Data
      wp_reset_postdata();
    }        
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its not clear what the goal is here, but here are some suggestions:

- In general, the `pre_get_posts` hook is not a good place to instantiate a  secondary query to display HTML.
- Your current setup will result in an **infinite-loop**, because when you instantiate `WP_Query` within the `pre_get_posts` callback, you will instantiate it recursively, until you reach the recursive limit with an error.
- There are ways to instantiate a `WP_Query` within the `pre_get_posts`, by removing the callback after the first run, but I don't think that's what you're after.
- Remove this part from your function:

  ```
  if( is_home() && $query->is_main_query()){
      global $wp_query;
  ```

  and e.g. display the function in your home template instead. Note that  `$query` is undefined in that line.
- There's also the handy `get_template_part()` if you want to resuse template partials.
- You might also want to consider a proper function prefix, instead of `my_`, to avoid possible name collisions.

Comment: I just wanted to figure out how to modify the main query. In the example above I mixed something up, I didn't want to instantiate a second query. Now my code works using `$query->set('posts_per_Page' => 3)` inside the `pre_get_posts`-function.

Comment: Glad to hear you got this working. PS: Just remember to pass on the `WP_Query` object (e.g. as `$query` ) as an input argument for the `pre_get_posts` callback. It's missing in the `my_function(){` part of the code snippet you posted in the question. @newjonnydepony

Comment: Thanks for reminding me of this. After many `Internal Server Errors (ERROR 500)` I found it out that I need to pass the `WP_Query` object as an argument.

Comment: Always have the `WP_DEBUG` constant as true on your test install so you can see or log the warnings. More [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress). @newjonnydepony

Comment: You're welcome - Best of luck with your project @newjonnydepony